# In Ogre, how to get the depth buffer value?

Tags: ogre

I am rendering an object to a texture using the following setup code which I copied from Ogre's rendering to texture tutorial:

```
Ogre::RenderTexture *renderTexture = rtt_texture->getBuffer()->getRenderTarget();

renderTexture->addViewport(myViewPoint); //the original code uses mCamera, but I want
//to render the scene from a different view point.
renderTexture->getViewport(0)->setClearEveryFrame(true);
renderTexture->getViewport(0)->setBackgroundColour(Ogre::ColourValue::Black);
renderTexture->getViewport(0)->setOverlaysEnabled(false);
```

Is there any way I can get the depth value at runtime as seen from `myViewPoint`?

I tried to use:

```
Ogre::GLDepthBuffer *depthBuf = renderTexture->getDepthBuffer();
```

but it didn't compile and the compiler says `GLDepthBuffer is not a member of Ogre`.

Comment: Do you need the depth values in C++ code or for the use in a shader?

Comment: @PhilipAllgaier I need them in C++ code.

Comment: For OpenGL or D3D?

Comment: @PhilipAllgaier  For OpenGL!

Comment: The question as asked can be answered, but it may be useful to know _why_ you think you need the depth value. I don't know your situation of course, but from experience I'm willing to bet that you don't _need_ the depth value at all and you would be much better served by a ray test in your physics world. Remember that accessing the GPU's depth buffer from CPU code is _slooooooow_ and that the depth buffer doesn't even necessarily model the data that you want (esp. when translucent object rendering is added to the mix).

Answer (score 1):

To use the class "GLDepthBuffer", you will have to manually include (and link) the OpenGL RenderSystem into your application (since that class is part of that Ogre plugin):

```
#include <RenderSystems/GL/OgreGLDepthBuffer.h>
```

However, Ogre currently does not provide a direct way to retrieve the depth buffer. The following code will help you to get the GLDepthBuffer instance:

```
Ogre::DepthBuffer* pDepthBuffer = OgreFramework::getSingletonPtr()->m_pViewport->getTarget()->getDepthBuffer();

if(OgreFramework::getSingletonPtr()->m_pRoot->getRenderSystem()->getName().find("OpenGL") != Ogre::String::npos)
{
    Ogre::GLDepthBuffer* pGlDepthBuffer = static_cast<Ogre::GLDepthBuffer*>(pDepthBuffer);
    Ogre::GLRenderBuffer* pRenderBuffer = pGlDepthBuffer->getDepthBuffer(); 
}
```

Unfortunately, the last line will not yield the expected result, since that will only return a null pointer as [described in the API](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/1.9/class_ogre_1_1_g_l_depth_buffer.html#details).

**Bottom-line:** You will have to find a way to access the depth buffer in OpenGL via the context (Ogre::GLContext and its subclasses for various platforms) or the FBOs. As a starting point, search the following method in the Ogre code base (part of multiple classes):

```
getCustomAttribute( const String& name, void* pData )
```

Alternatively you can also retrieve the context by adding the following lines below the previous code snippet (on Windows; other platforms have similar ways):

```
Ogre::GLContext* pGLContext = pGlDepthBuffer->getGLContext();

if(WIN32)
{
    Ogre::Win32Context* pWinContext = static_cast<Ogre::Win32Context*>(pGLContext);
}
```

If you found a way, please let us know either on the [forums](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums) or even better, create a pull-request for our repository on BitBucket and we might merge it in.